# With Windows 2008 R2 how do I audit when an user is added and removed from a local group?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, auditing

I want to keep an audit when I remove or add users from local groups. Is it possible to filter out which groups? If not, all local groups is fine.

Comment: Look into audit policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically looking for two events in the [Security eventlog](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21561).

- `4732`   A member was added to a security-enabled local group.
- `4733`   A member was removed from a security-enabled local group.

When using the following commandline you get a new instance of the eventviewer filtered on those two events.

```
eventvwr /f:"<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Security'><Select Path='Security'>*[System[(EventID=4732 or EventID=4733)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>"
```

An other option is to use the [WMIC tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx) from the commandline (make sure you are using an elevated commandprompt)

```
wmic ntevent where "LogFile='security' and (EventIdentifier=4732 or EventIdentifier=4733)"
```

Do notice that this uses [Win32_NTLogEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394226(v=vs.85).aspx) internally and I had to use the `/trace:on` switch to figure out the correct syntax for the where clause.
Use the optional `/record:filename.xml` to store the results in an xml file or simply redirect the output to a csv file.

One other option you have is to use powershell:

```
get-eventlog -logname security | where {$_.InstanceId -eq 4732 -or $_.InstanceId -eq 4733}
```

Last one I povide is by writing a small c# program that uses the [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
var list = new EventLog { Log = "Security" }
            .Entries
            .Cast<EventLogEntry>()
            .Where(evl => evl.InstanceId == 4732 || evl.InstanceId == 4733)
            .Select(cv => cv.Message);
foreach (var msg in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine(msg);   
}
```

Take your pick

Comment: If I decide to writeup the last option a c# program..how do I wire it up to trigger or run with windows server? Scheduler?

Comment: Shedule a taks with SCHTASKS. You can use the /? switch to see the options or search on superuser.com for similar questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help,Enjoy your Christmas!